# While loop use for create inbox table using but it show me the 1st message allways

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I create a message inbox table using while loop with bootstrap modal but it show me always the 1st message. I'm new in mysql and php. need help I added icon when some user click on that icon it will give another modal box which contain the message details

```
 <!-- Start Inbox modal -->
      <div id="inbox_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    include 'sql.php';

        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM messaging WHERE to_receiver = '$user' ORDER BY date_send DESC";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        while  ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $ctrl = $db_field['ctrl_no'];
            $a = $db_field['opened'];
            $b = $db_field['from_sender'];
            $c = $db_field['mail_subject'];
            $d = $db_field['date_send'];

               ?><tr>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#read_mail" href="read_mail<?php print ".$ctrl."; ?>"><i class="<?php  if ($a == 0) { echo'icon-lock';} else{echo'icon-unlock';} ?>"></i></a></td>
                   <td><?php print $b;?></td>
                   <td><?php print $c;?></td>
                   <td><?php print $d;?></td>
                   <td>
                   <a href="reply_mail.php?key=<?php print $b; ?>">&nbsp;<i class="icon-reply"></i></a>
                   <a href="delete_mail.php?key=<?php print $ctrl; ?>">&nbsp;<i class=" icon-trash"></i></a>
                   </td>
                   </tr>
                   <?php
                   }
                   ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>

  </div>

</div>
```

```
<!-- Read inbox Messages -->
```

×
        Read Mail

```
$SQL = "UPDATE messaging SET opened = 1 WHERE ctrl_no = '$ctrl'";
mysql_query($SQL);


$SQL = "SELECT * FROM messaging WHERE ctrl_no = '$ctrl'";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
if( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $a = $db_field['opened'];
            $b = $db_field['from_sender'];
            $c = $db_field['mail_subject'];
            $d = $db_field['date_send'];

}


?>  <h2>Form:<?php print $b ?></h2>
    <p>Date:<?php print $d; ?></p>
    <h4>Sub:<?php print $c; ?></h4>
    <p>Msg<?php print $mess; ?></p>
  </div>
```